# Can you change the mysql prompt?

Tags: mysql

I use the "mysql" command-line tool all the time, and frequently forget what database (schema) I'm on.

Is there a way to change the prompt?  It'd be much more useful to see `foo_bar_schema>` than `mysql>` all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [`mysql` commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html).

You can change the prompt to just the current database by typing using this command:

```
prompt \d>\_
```

Comment: That documentation link will also help you make the change permanent.